# Auto run a shell script when connecting to a network? (wifi or utp)

Tags: network, applescript, wifi, script, automation

Is there a way to make macOS run a custom script whenever it (re)connects to any WiFi or Ethernet network?

Basically, whenever my macbook connects to any network (wired or wireless) I would like to automatically run a shell script, e.g. I want `~/AutoRunOnConnect.sh` to be executed. Is that possible somehow?

FYI I'm running macOS 10.15 (Catalina) with all the latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program named [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) which among the *events* it monitors, there are [Network Events](https://www.mousedown.net/software/Event_Parameters.html#table1-j), i.e., **Internet became available**, **Internet became unavailable**, **External IP address changed** and **Wireless network changed**. Update: In the latest release there is also a **Wireless network reconnected** *event* not shown on the linked webpage.

It uses **AppleScript** *scripts* to preform the *action(s)* you want to have happen when a given *event* is triggered.

You can execute a *shell command/script* using the **AppleScript** `do shell script` *command*.

Not sure if any of these can be adopted for your use, and it will probably require some additional *coding*, either in **AppleScript** or *shell script* to validate the conditions are met for wanting the main *shell script* to run. Just wanted to offer a possible solution.

---

It is a paid app, $4.99 USD, but does have a demo version you can download to test with before purchasing.

- [Mac App Store Preview (US)](https://apps.apple.com/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12)
- [Download for Demo](https://www.mousedown.net/software/Downloads.html)

---

<sup>Note: Other then being a paid user of this app, I have no affiliation with its developer.</sup>